# PowerShell Regex Matching content after a number of forward slashes and before the last one

Tags: regex, powershell

**Using PowerShell I am trying to use Regex on the example string to capture everything starting at the third "/" and stop before the last "/".  Do you know the best Regex example to do this?**

**Example Test String: (structure is the same but text could be random)**

```
/example/text/istyped/HERE.TXT
/example/text/canbetyped/HERE.TXT
/example/text/sometimestyped/HERE.TXT
```

**CODE EXAMPLE**

```
$Example = '/example/text/typed/HERE.TXT    # This $Example is imported from CSV
/example/text/istyped/HERE.TXT
/example/text/canbetyped/HERE.TXT
/example/text/sometimestyped/HERE.TXT'

$Output = $Example | where { $_.ExampleHeader -match '(My Pattern Here' }
$Output
```

**My Output should simply be:**

```
/typed
/istyped
/canbetyped
/sometimestyped
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recurring character in your input string you want split it on you can use the `-split` operator and pick the desired element with the index of the resulting array:

```
$Example = @'
/example/text/typed/HERE.TXT
/example/text/istyped/HERE.TXT
/example/text/canbetyped/HERE.TXT
/example/text/sometimestyped/HERE.TXT
'@ -split "`n"

foreach($element in $Example){
    ($element -split '/')[3]
}
```

The Output would look like this:

```
typed
istyped
canbetyped
sometimestyped
```

Of course you can add a slash in front of every element if you really need. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to construct your regex pattern by searching with the end of the string.

Something like that should do the job :

```
.+(\/[^\/]+)\/.+$
```

this way, you capture the last group between to slashes. It is certainly perfectible :)

You can test it here :
https://regex101.com/r/Ne5IVQ/1